# Linq list of objects to json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, http-get

My goal is to make a linq query and convert it to a Json in order to return it from an Api.

**Query:**

```
var results = _context.User.ToList();
```

This List has multiple Users with multiple attributes e.g. username, first name, last name, but I don't get how to return them as a json...

I need to have to **convert them to json objects**.

```
return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

---

### Edit

Everytime I run the code I get an circular reference exception?

Comment: the line you wrote not works?

Comment: write like ``return Json(new {result = results }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);``

Comment: Then I am running into a ciruclar reference exception... Don't know why

Comment: Well, do the objects that you're serializing contain a circular reference? We can't tell you without seeing the data.

Comment: I have a "Roles" column which refers to another table, it is a foreignkey, does this occur my exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a circular reference in your data. Try getting only the fields you need:

```
var results = _context.User.Select(u => new { u.FirstName, u.LastName }).ToList();
```

If you want something in another table that points back to User, then you'll have to take some steps to prevent the circular reference.

Comment: There's also no point in the `ToList()`. Either leave it out and let the `Json()` method work directly on the enumerable without loading it into a list first, or `await` on `ToListAsync()` so the thread doesn't have to block on retrieving from the database.